# variable (named as SECONDS) in bash script automatically changes after sleep is added

Tags: bash, shell, variables, command-line-arguments

In my bash script, I tried to assign the argument to a variable and use that variable later, but after I introduced line of sleep, it is found that variable value is changed automatically by adding the number of seconds of that sleep operation.
The code is like this (file name chk2.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

SECONDS=$1

echo "seconds: $1"
echo "seconds: $SECONDS"
sleep 5;
echo "seconds: $SECONDS"
```

The output is this:

```
./chk2.sh 4
seconds: 4
seconds: 4
seconds: 9
```

I expected the variable $SECONDS is not changing and can be used later.
However, the value is actually changed after using sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> expected the variable $SECONDS is not changing and can be used later. However, the value is actually changed after using sleep.

```
declare -p SECONDS
```

has a value, check the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html).

```
PAGER='less +/^[[:blank:]]*seconds' man bash
```

---

- There is a reason for the convention for not using upper case variable names. Bash and env variables are all upper cased, so this is a classic example.
- See: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Comment: Thanks! Yes the manual says: SECONDS
This variable expands to the number of seconds since the shell was started. Assignment to this variable resets the count to the value assigned, and the expanded value becomes the value assigned plus the number of seconds since the assignment. The number of seconds at shell invocation and the current time are always determined by querying the system clock. If SECONDS is unset, it loses its special properties, even if it is subsequently reset.